# Receive callbacks from HtmlPage host in Silverlight

Tags: javascript, silverlight

I'd like to receive callbacks from Javascript code to my Silverlight host *without* using ScriptableAttribute.  I've seen it done before, but I couldn't work out how they did it.  Has anyone got any ideas?  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple enough use:-

```
 HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("someJavascriptFunc", "Hello", "World");
```

In the javascript in the page hosting the silverlight have:-

```
 function someJavascriptFunc(p1, p2)
 {
     alert(p1 + ' ' + p2);
 }
```

**Edit**:  Ken is right the above is the wrong way round.

Lets say you have this function in Silverlight:-

```
string GetStuff(string name)
{
     return "Hello " + name;
}
```

You can now make this function available to javascript like this:-

```
HtmlPage.Window.SetProperty("sayHello", new Func<string, string>(GetStuff));
```

Now code in javascript can simply do something like this:-

```
alert(sayHello("Fred"));
```

Comment: That's the opposite direction, I think: from SL to JS.  I think he wants the other way, from JS to SL.

Comment: I hadn't seen that technique before. Nice.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using events, in theory, you can use AttachEvent to subscribe to events.  That's not quite the same thing as callbacks, but it's close.

Caveats: I haven't tested AttachEvent on Mozilla-based browsers (where the appropriate JS command is "addEventListener()" rather than "attachEvent()"), and I've had trouble getting AttachEvent() to work reliably even in IE.  So I've always just used the [ScriptableMember] attribute, and called that from JS.  Is there a reason you don't want to use that?  (I'd be curious to hear if anyone has any better ideas.)